# R error: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'

Tags: r

I'm trying to perform a RDA analysis in the vegan package using the `varpart` function.

I have a matrix of community structure data in different sites (rows), which I want to explain using 3 matrices of environmental data. The 3 matrices are:

- water quality parameters;
- local land use variables;
- total land use variables.

In each matrix, the number of the rows is the same (the sites) and there are different column number (measured varibakes).

I use the follow script:

```
WQ_RDA <- read.csv("F:/Sher_sophi_new3/RDA/WQ_RDA_1.csv", row.names = 1)
LU2_loc_RDA <- read.csv("F:/Sher_sophi_new3/RDA/LU2_loc_RDA_1.csv", row.names = 1)
LU2_bas_RDA <- read.csv("F:/Sher_sophi_new3/RDA/LU2_basin_RDA_1.csv",  row.names = 1)
comm <- read.csv("F:/Sher_sophi_new3/RDA/Final_true_OTUs_97_1.csv",  row.names = 1)

x1 = as.matrix(WQ_RDA)
x2 = as.matrix(LU2_loc_RDA)
x3 = as.matrix(LU2_bas_RDA)
comm = as.matrix(t(comm))

RDA_Ger = varpart(comm, x1, x2, x3, transfo="hellinger", scale = FALSE, 
                  na.action = na.omit)
```

I get this error message:

> ''Error in as.vector(x, mode) :    cannot coerce type 'closure' to
>   vector of type 'any'

Can anyone help me figure out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Before casting my close vote I also searched on that error message combined with "vegan". Do not see any obvious source of a function name being "taken in vain".